# Pairs in a list

Tags: java, algorithm

What is the most optimal way to find unique pairs of all numbers in a list in Java? I have a solution where I convert the list into an array and then basically pair the first element with 2nd , then first with 3rd and so on.. However, this turns out to be O(n^2). 
Here is my basic pseudo code:

```
int arr[] = convertListToArray(arrList) 
   for i=1;i< arr.length; i++
     for j =1+1; j<arr.length; j++
          print arr[i] , arr[j]
```

This is clearly o(n^2). Can this be done in a better way?

Comment: Sort it first and then just iterate over the array?

Answer (score 5):

There are some tricks you can do in some situations if the number set is constrained. Fundamentally your problem is n^2 though so in the general case you don't have many alternatives.

If you only need unique pairs then you can remove duplicates from the `List` (for example by dumping it into a `Set` then back out again) and then iterate over it.

Iterating over all unique pairs would then be:

```
for (int i=0;i<len;i++) {
    for (j=i+1;j<len;j++) {
    }
}
```

Note that j loops from i+1 onwards so this is a bit better than the n^2 case although it is still non-linear growth.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no duplicates, there will be N choose 2 = N(N-1)/2 different pairs, which is clearly O(N^2). Avoiding duplicates can be done by first removing duplicates in the original list (this would be an additional O(N log N) operation). Note that this would remove any pairs of equal values though.

Comment: Removing duplicates would be `O(n)` as you can just dump the contents into a `Set` which has an `O(1)` `add()`.

Answer (score 0):

This code finds duplicates in `O(n)`. Adding an item to a `HashSet` takes `O(1)`. We add `n` items, hence it takes `O(n)`. here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6 });
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer value : list) {
        if (!set.add(value)) System.out.printf("%d is at least a duplicate\n", value);
    }
}
```